# Converse to Exactness of localization of modules

Tags: modules, examples-counterexamples, exact-sequence

It is a standard fact that if $R$ is a ring, and
$$\tag{1}
0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow 0
$$
a short exact sequence of $R$-modules, if $S$ is a multiplicative subset of $R$, then passing to quotients, the sequence
$$\tag{2}
0\longrightarrow S^{-1}A\overset{S^{-1}f}{\longrightarrow}S^{-1}B\overset{S^{-1}g}{\longrightarrow}S^{-1}C\longrightarrow 0
$$
is exact as well. However, I cannot find a counterexample for the converse, that is, non-exact sequences (1) such that (2) is a short exact sequence. Any insight greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is if $S^{-1}R$ is a faithfully flat $R$-module. It isn't, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $A=B=C=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and the maps $A\to B$ and $B\to C$ being the zero maps, and consider $S=\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$.

Comment: The first sequence is not exact, but why would the sequence $0\to \mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}\to S^{-1}C\to 0$ where $S^{-1}C=\{0\}\cup\{1/n~|~n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ be exact? Am I missing something? Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Laurent I made a mistake, sorry :) See if it's cool now.

Comment: Just a remark: in fact $S^{-1}R$ is faithfully flat as an $R$-module iff $S^{-1}R \cong R$, i.e. a nontrivial localization is never faithfully flat

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks for checking. In the current edit, if all your maps are zero, clearly the initial sequence is not exact, but does that not imply that the map induced are zero as well, giving a non-exact sequence also? Since $S^{-1}u$ is defined on $m/s$ by $u(m)/s$, if $u\equiv 0$, then $S^{-1}u\equiv 0$ as well?

Comment: @Laurent The original sequence is not exact, but when you tensor with $\mathbb{Q}$, which is the same thing as localizing at $\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, which kills all the finite groups, leaving you with the sequence of all zeros, which is exact for trivial reasons.

Comment: @zcn Certainly, since, by definition, the induced map $\text{Spec}(S^{-1}R)\to\text{Spec}(R)$ is not surjective.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I assumed you were trying to kill all the groups but do you have a reference explaining this fact? That $ M\otimes_\mathbb {Z}\mathbb {Q}\cong S^{-1} M$ with $S=\mathbb {Z}-{0} $?